# ¿Cómo le dicen en su país: "planta eléctrica" o "grupo electrógeno"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, vocabulario-técnico

En Colombia se denomina **planta eléctríca** a aquellos aparatos para generar energía eléctrica por medio de dínamo acoplado a un motor de combustión interna.

Resulta que en Argentina denominan al mismo aparato **grupo electrógeno**.

En inglés se denomina "**power plant**".

Ejemplo de un aparato **portátil** o **móvil**:

[image: Planta eléctrica portátil]

Ejemplo de un aparato **fijo** como para edificios o centro comerciales, industria:

[image]

¿Cuál de las dos expresiones usan en su país?

Comment: Cree una respuesta wiki porque de lo contrario esto caería en off-topic por "too broad" o por "opinion based"

Comment: @DGaleano no veo porqué las respuestas serían una opinión ni tampoco considero que sea amplio espectro, ya que se refiere a como llaman algo específico en cada país que usan el español como lengua nativa.

Comment: Porque no podrías marcar una respuesta como la correcta. Esa es la filosofía del stack.

Comment: In English, "power plant" is only used to refer to large scale facilities, such as those that power cities. Small units like the ones pictured are generally called "generators".

Answer (score 4):

En Chile, trabajando como maestro eléctrico, he escuchado ambos conceptos:

Como *grupo electrógeno* nos referimos a los dispositivos que, portátiles o no, generan energía mediante un motor de combustión interna.

En cambio por *planta eléctrica* nos referimos a las instalaciones de generación eléctrica, que conlleva una edificación, con personas trabajando en ella.

Answer (score 3):

#### Generador (también *~ eléctrico*)

- España ([imágenes](https://www.google.es/search?q=generador&tbm=isch))
- México

#### Generador de energía

- México

#### Grupo electrógeno

- Argentina
- Chile
- España

#### Planta de luz

- México ([Ref](https://listado.mercadolibre.com.mx/herramientas-y-construccion/herramientas/generadores-electricos/planta-de-luz))

#### Planta eléctrica

- Colombia
- Ecuador ([Ref](https://www.ecured.cu/Planta_el%C3%A9ctrica))

Answer (score 0):

En Puerto Rico la llamamos “planta eléctrica”, pero comúnmente solo “planta”.